# Javascript Node Read from CSV file and store data into object

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

Trying to read a csv file and store data from it into an object which I can then use for other tasks.

```
    var csv = require('csv');

    var obj = csv();

    var filename = process.argv[2];

    function Employee(eno, ename, sal) {

        this.EmpNo = eno;
        this.EmpName = ename;
        this.Salary = sal;
    };

    var Employee = {};

    obj.from.path(filename).to.array(function (data) {
        for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
               Employees.push(new Employee(data[index][0], data[index][1], data[index][2]));
        }
    });

console.log(Employee);
```

When running this I get the error:

```
var obj = csv();
          ^

TypeError: csv is not a function
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

Changed to this as per answer below but cannot get the string to be populated outside the function:

```
string = {}

var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(filename)
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    var splitLine = line.split(',');

        string[splitLine[0]] = {
            name: splitLine[0],
            dob: splitLine[1],
            employeeid: splitLine[2],
            country: domain,
            zone: splitLine[4],
            type: splitLine[5],
            id: splitLine[7],
            number: splitLine[8]
        }

    lineReader.close()
    }
})

console.log(string)
```

Comment: Please check package documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv

Comment: @NitishkumarSingh i've seen the usage of this here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/nodejs/1204/read-csv-file-using-nodejs  what is the best library to use to read a file and store into an object to use outside of the stream?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [documentation](http://csv.adaltas.com/csv/) for the module, it looks like you're not quite using it correctly. `csv` is not a constructor, but instead has methods which you should call. There are some [examples](http://csv.adaltas.com/csv/examples/) available which should guide you towards correct usage.

Callback example from the module website;

```
var csv = require('csv');

csv.generate({seed: 1, columns: 2, length: 20}, function(err, data){
  csv.parse(data, function(err, data){
    csv.transform(data, function(data){
      return data.map(function(value){return value.toUpperCase()});
    }, function(err, data){
      csv.stringify(data, function(err, data){
        process.stdout.write(data);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

If you want to read from a file, and append the contents to an array;

Input

```
name,age
Alex,24
Sam,99
```

Code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');
var strings = [];

var readStream = fs.createReadStream('./input.csv');

var parser = csv.parse({columns:true});

parser.on('readable', function() {
  while(record = parser.read()) {
    strings.push(record);
  }
});

parser.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
});

parser.on('finish', (function() {
  console.log(strings);
}));

readStream.pipe(parser);
```

Output

```
[ { name: 'Alex', age: '24' }, { name: 'Sam', age: '99' } ]
```

Comment: Okay thanks will take a look but I got the use of this from these sites which seemed to work: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/nodejs/1204/read-csv-file-using-nodejs

http://csv.adaltas.com/legacy/from/

Comment: @Sam That article is 2 years old, it could be that the API for csv has changed since then. Always good to check the docs!

Comment: Okay thanks Alex, using the example above can I write the data from a file store it into an object to use outside of the stream? If not would you know of a good library where I can do that and use lexical scoping?

Comment: You could use the `fs` module to read the file as a stream, and then `stream-tranform` by the maker of `csv` to append the objects to an array. You want `fs.createReadStream('file.csv');` Personally, I use the pipe syntax.

Comment: I have used the fs.createReadStream(file.csv) before and from it just split the lines and stored into and object using that. But if I want to use that array outside of the lineReader method I can't as it's always empty which means I need to put all the logic within the lineReader.on method. Would you know a way I can use the array outside of the method scope?

Comment: This is great thanks this is something I can work with, thanks for your help. I see you use .push to make string=[] retrievable. Is there a method like .push I can use for an object like string={} as .push doesn't seem to be working here?

Comment: You could assign attributes to the object, based off, for example, the name in my example. `strings[record.name] = record.age` would create an object of `{'Alex':24,'Sam':99}`, but why would you not use an array? Please move this to chat, I don't have high enough reputation.

Comment: hmm says your reputation is not high enough to chat. I will edit the above and add the code I'm using. I need it to be in objects as the name has to be retrievable to idenify each object and also the other code relies it to be in that format. See above, I appreciate your help

Comment: If you could just show me how to make the object data retrievable outside the function that would be awesome. Thanks